# Android Studio org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException on new empty project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

1. My OS is win8.1
2. I have downloaded Android Studio version:
   `android-studio-ide-173.4720617-windows.exe` and have install it. (I had to do `mklink /D "c:\Android-Sdk" "C:\Users\мет\AppData\Local\Android\sdk"` because of ASCII issue)
3. I have started Android Studio and have choosen `Start new Android Studio project`
4. `Application name` and everything else is left as set by default.
5. Have checked `Phone and Tablet`.
6. Have choosen `Empty activity`.
7. `Activity name` and everything else is left as set by default.
8. Clicked `Finish` button and got on build error:

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task
>   ':app:mergeDebugResources'.   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceException: Error:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error:
>   check logs for details    at
>   com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.java:296)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
>     ... 32 more Caused by: Error:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error:
>   check logs for details    at
>   com.android.ide.common.res2.MergedResourceWriter.end(MergedResourceWriter.java:332)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.common.res2.DataMerger.mergeData(DataMerger.java:301)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceMerger.mergeData(ResourceMerger.java:412)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.java:285)
>     ... 48 more     Suppressed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Some file
>   processing failed, see logs for details       at
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.QueuedResourceProcessor.waitForAll(QueuedResourceProcessor.java:121)
>         at
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.QueuedResourceProcessor.end(QueuedResourceProcessor.java:141)
>         at
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.close(QueueableAapt2.java:104)
>         at
>   com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.java:293)
>         ... 48 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error:
>   check logs for details    at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
>     at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:462)
>     at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.common.res2.MergedResourceWriter.end(MergedResourceWriter.java:327)
>     ... 51 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error:
>   check logs for details    at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
>     at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:462)
>     at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.lambda$compile$0(QueueableAapt2.java:136)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     ... 1 more Caused by:
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error:
>   check logs for details    at
>   com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.handleOutput(AaptProcess.java:443)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.err(AaptProcess.java:395)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$ProcessOutputFacade.err(AaptProcess.java:312)
>     at
>   com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$1.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:104)

Can anyone help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to fix this issue. Just in case if anyone else comes in this kind of a problem, I will decribe what I found and how I managed to fix the issue.

1. First I tried to find out what was the real error. To do that, I run `gradlew.bat packageDebug` from `cmd` as `administrator`. You can do that from `Terminal` in `Android Studio` as well. The error that I got was about Android Studio not able to find some files in `c:\users\?\.gradle\....` folder. Since I already had issue with ASCII during the installation process I knew that my user folder name containing non ASCII characters was the issue.
2. To solve this issue I needed to change user folder name. I did it like described in this [article.](https://www.repairwin.com/how-to-rename-user-and-user-folder-in-windows-7-8-10/) 
   After I changed user folder name, everything worked fine and my errors are gone. I can't believe that Android Studio can't work with Unicode and is stuck with ASCII. That is great disapointment. 
   I hope this will help to someone.

Comment: Yeah, it was a horrible bug in AAPT2. It is fixed now so if you use android gradle plugin 3.2.0-alpha11 or newer (newest one is 3.2.0-alpha17 I think) it will work without changing the user folder name.

Comment: @Izabela Orlowska  Thanks for the tip. I will try the new version of gradle, but since I already changed user folder name I can't test it now. :-)